# How to link images in kohana?

Tags: php, kohana

I'm getting started using Kohana framework. How do I properly link images? I'm linking images using the usual way:

```
<img src="../../resources/images/img01.jpg" />
```

I'm using dreamweaver, and I can see that the link is correct. Since I can see an image in the preview:
[image]

The link is still the same when I reference the image based on the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to use full (base)paths:

```
<img src="<?php echo url::base() ?>resources/images/img01.jpg" />
```

or:

```
<img src="<?php echo url::site('resources/images/img01.jpg') ?>" />
```

Comment: make sure the path to your image is correct. url::base will end up at: `http://base_path.ext/resources/images/img01.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use absolute links. Either use html::image(), or prefix your image with url::base(), or use url::site(). There's lots of options, read the documentation.